# wordpress - failed to load resource - undefined resource

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce, xml-rpc

I have wordpress/woocommerce site that have error: "failed to load resource" on inspect element. This resource is undefined, it costs 2 seconds of load time and the problem is that I can't find what it is. All images, scripts, etc are loading correctly.

In attachment is screenshot of Network tab in inspect element (Chrome) where you can see what I'm talking about. In second screenshot you can see "header" of that undefined element. From that I'm suspecting that it's something maybe from woocommerce add to cart functionality (on home page there is no add to cart possibility), wordpress xmlr rpc (but I disabled that).

I checked everything and I can't find where is this little bugger coming from.

Thank you for your help

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you share a link to the page?

Comment: When an array element or variable is missing in JavaScript, and you try to access it, it gives you an `undefined` value. And JavaScript automatically converts values to strings where needed. So I think somewhere in the JS code, it's trying to load an image or something, and it's using a variable that doesn't exist, getting an `undefined`, and JavaScript interprets that as the URL `./undefined`

Comment: link is http://1klik.com.hr/

Comment: Have you disabled your minification plugin?

Comment: @Andrea do you know maybe how can I find this missing image or something? Maybe some kind of javascript debugger that can point me to the broken line in code or if I can just know which image is it.

Comment: @doublesharp minifaction plugin is up and running (minification didn't caused the problem because I noticed that error before I made minifications)

Comment: @Andrea you could look through the JS source and see where it tries to create images, then set a breakpoint, but this would be hard if it's minified JavaScript